# Redirect to request URL after msal token validation

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

Below is the routing module, After clearing cache when I try to access page with direct url (locahost:4200/create) it is being redirected for microsoft token validation after successful token validation it's being redirected to home instead of requested URL which is 'create'

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: () => import('src/home').then((m) => {
    return m.home;
  }),
},
{
  path: 'create',
  loadChildren: () => import('src/createpage').then((m) => {
    return m.createpage;
  }),
},
```

config file

```
auth: {
    clientId: 'clientID',
    authority: 'authority',
    // redirectUri: 'redirectUri'),
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    protectedResourceMap: 'protectedResourceMap',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'postLogoutRedirectUri'
},
```

I tried changing config in config file from `home` to `window.location.origin` and added             `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,`

Below is the earlier config. In both cases it's not working

```
auth: {
    clientId: 'clientID',
    authority: 'authority',
    // redirectUri: 'redirectUri'),
    redirectUri: 'localhost:4200/home',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    protectedResourceMap: 'protectedResourceMap',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'postLogoutRedirectUri'
},
```